# Match undone in sparse tree

Tags: org-mode

Is there any expression that matches all undone TODO states in a sparse-tree search?

Meaning: what's the shortest expression I can write if I do `C-c / m` that renders the same results as `C-c / t`?

Answer (score 0):

With a prefix argument (`C-u`) to exclude non-TODO headlines, matching `-DONE` will get you close (unless you have several different DONE states).

Answer (score 0):

Missed/forgot, and it's in the manual, that the answer is simply `/!`